# How to log SQL calls with NHibernate to the console of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nhibernate, logging, log4net

I have the following configuration file for [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=mydb;Integrated Security=True;</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.release_mode">auto</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">500</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But the SQL doesn't show in the output window of Visual Studio. Is it mandatory to install [log4net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_log4net)? Or should `show_sql` work alone?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To show the SQL in the output window of Visual Studio, configure log4net to use TraceAppender in your log4net config. This:

```
<appender name="DebugSQL" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Then this:

```
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="DebugSQL" />
</logger>
```

EDIT: I can't seem to format this correctly here. [See this link for code example](http://suspendedwithpay.wordpress.com/2009/04/03/displaying-nhibernate-sql-in-visual-studios-output-window/)

Comment: it doesn't appear to support VS2010 with .NET 4.0

Comment: @Alex it works in VS2010 with .NET4 for me, perhaps you forgot to call log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); in your Application_Start? (or perhaps it's since been fixed)

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer? I don't think the owner of the question was searching for paid products! Really men, SO is becaming more and more polluted by software house trying to sell their products! Stop it!

Comment: Can I use it in Unit Test ?

Answer (score 18):

For those who prefer code rather than configuration, the following snippet will create the appropriate NH logger with a simple console appender.

```
var hierarchy = (Hierarchy) LogManager.GetRepository();
var logger = (Logger) hierarchy.GetLogger("NHibernate.SQL");
logger.AddAppender(new ConsoleAppender {Layout = new SimpleLayout()});
hierarchy.Configured = true;
```

Comment: I had to use TraceAppender instead of ConsoleAppender to see this in the Visual Studio output window.

Comment: you also must to add logger.Level = Level.Debug

Answer (score 8):

`show_sql` outputs to `Console.Out` - it's most useful when running integration tests

Comment: does it mean no way to see it in VS? Does it mean I must install log4net?

Comment: TestDriven.NET sends Console.Out to the output window in VS.  That's how I use show_sql

Comment: If you run it under NUnit, it shows up in NUnit's Text Output tab.  If you run it in a plain old app, methinks it should show up in a Console window.  It goes wherever Console.Out goes.  You should not need to do anything with log4net.

Answer (score 6):

Since NHibernate 3.0 you can use loquacious configuration

```
configuration.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
{
  x.LogSqlInConsole = true;
  x.LogFormattedSql = true;
});
```

Others info available at http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com.ar/2009/07/nhibernate-configuration-through.html

Comment: what is ***configuration*** ? Not in  _NHibernate  3.3.0.4000_

Answer (score 4):

There is something called NHibernate profiler you can use.

http://nhprof.com/

it's pricey but it works and it has a 30 day trial.