# How to log all the request to the sql server database?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I'm working on some code that hit the database several times through NHibernate. I'd like to see how I can write a procedure.

To ease my work, this is what I want:

- Initiate the operation from the UI
- Log all the request to the DB from the beginning to the end.
- Know the statements that the DB execute for each request.

I'd like to log information from the prospective of the DB. I tried before to follow all the codes that make request to the database.

Thank for helping

Comment: In addition to these excellent suggestions, you can also configure nhibernate to emit the sql to the console or configure log4net to emit NHibernate.SQL to a text file or database

Comment: I believe that what you seek is here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474659/how-to-log-sql-calls-with-nhibernate-to-the-console-of-visual-studio


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819040/how-to-know-query-generated-by-fluent-nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with nhibernate I suggest you to give Rhino a try.

[Rhino](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof)

Comment: Any reason why this was downvoted? I love SqlServer Profiler but for nHibernate I found Rhino better as it helps with code analysis.