# How to show SQL in Visual Studio console using fluent nhibernate?

Tags: c#, sql, fluent-nhibernate, show

I'm trying to show the SQL in the console of Visual Studio but it doesn't work. I'm using fluent nhibernate with the following code:

```
string connectionString = WebCondStaClara.Lib.ConfigDB.StringConexao;

ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
                MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connectionString).ShowSql
            )
            .Mappings(m =>
                m.FluentMappings
                    .AddFromAssemblyOf<Person>()
                    .AddFromAssemblyOf<Home>()
            )
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
            .Create(true, false)).BuildSessionFactory();

return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Fluent)NHibernate uses log4net to provide logging support. You have to configure log4net appropriately (build up a configuration with a console, debug or trace appender and let the loggers use these appenders).

Have a look here:
[How to log SQL calls with NHibernate to the console of Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474659/how-to-log-sql-calls-with-nhibernate-to-the-console-of-visual-studio/1360655)